# VSTS Kanban how to incorporate Test team work

Tags: testing, azure-devops, kanban

I'm looking for suggestions regarding how to incorporate Test team work to a VSTS Kanban board for continuous software development on a web application.

What makes the most sense to us initially is to implement this as two boards running concurrently such that for each Dev sprint our Test team is operating off a backlog created by the previous sprint.  For example:

```
DEV BOARD (current sprint)
+-------------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| DEV Backlog | Active | Code Complete | Peer Reviewed |
+-------------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| item7       |        |               |               |
|             | item6  |               |               |
|             |        | item5         |               |
|             |        |               | item4         |
+-------------+--------+---------------+---------------+
                                             /
                                            /
         _________________-----------------/
        /
       /
TEST BOARD (next sprint)
+-------------+--------+---------------+---------------+
|TEST Backlog | Active | Test Complete |   Deployed    |
+-------------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| item4       |        |               |               |
|             |        |               |               |
|             |        |               |               |
|             |        |               |               |
+-------------+--------+---------------+---------------+
```

But it's not clear how to implement this in VSTS.  Do we need to create two teams?  A Dev Team & a Test Team - with their own boards - and if we do, how then do we get the workflow configured such that what is completed in the current dev sprint feeds/fills the backlog for the next Test team sprint?

Suggestions appreciated and welcomed!  Thanks

Comment: Down voted?  Down vote is supposed to represent a lack of demonstrated research effort or a lack of clarity.  To the former, I'd have to ask: "Have you seen VSTS? It's ability to obfuscate what should be obvious and accessible is awe inspiring.  This is in no way obvious."  To the latter, what about this isn't clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create two teams with different areas, refer to these steps below:

1. Go to a team project setting page (`https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{team project}/_admin`
2. Click New team (Team name: `Dev Team`; Check `Create an area path with the name of the team` option)
3. Create a Tester Team as step 2
4. Create the work item with Dev Team area and related iteration, then you can see this work item in Work hub of Dev team, but cannot see it in Tester Team
5. After finishing dev workflow, you can change this work’s area path to Tester Team, then you can see this work item in Work hub of Tester Team

Note: You can manage **areas** and **Iterations** of each team in team’s admin page. `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{team project}/{team}/_admin/_work`